# Android: Define which encryption to use: AES 128 or AES 256

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

In an android project I am using

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

I would like to ask: Whether AES128 or AES256 is used, is defined by the key that is used? For example `key="012345678901234567890123456789012";` would have as a result AES256 to be used?

thanks
Thomas

Comment: All `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");` does is create the cipher. It will use AES128 if you give it a 128 bit key, or 256 if you give it a 256 bit key. Your example key is bogus. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/992413/492405) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes whether AES128 or AES256 is used is defined by the key that is in use.

However it's not the `String` length but the `byte[]` length that determines it. At some point in your code you should be converting `String` to `byte[]`. The size of resulting that `byte[]` is your key size. Without knowing how you convert `"012345678901234567890123456789012"`, it's not possible to know your encryption strength.

Alternatively you can use `KeyGenerator`:

```
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGen.init(128); // or 256

    // Generate the secret key specs
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    byte[] byteArray = secretKey.getEncoded();
```

Comment: You are fully right of course, but 32 characters are not very likely to result in less than 32 bytes, which would mean AES-256 - or failure. Java does - to my knowledge - not cut off or append key bytes as some other *idiotic* frameworks do.